# Get mobile data connectivity change in Nougat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, job-scheduling

Before Android 7 we could define a broadcast receiver as below to get the notified about the changes in the network including mobile data.

```
<receiver android:name=".reciever.DataStateChangedReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But as of Android 7, OS does not execute this broadcast receiver anymore as it's deprecated. I'm looking for a similar solution to achieve the same thing on Android 7 (figure out when mobile data state changes). Also, I'm aware that I can do this with dynamically registring broadcast in my Activity but That's not going to work for me because my app may be closed.

I'm looking for a solution to wake up my app whenever connectivity changes.

Comment: "I'm looking for a solution to wake up my app whenever connectivity changes." - thats exactly what google are trying to move away from. Use a foreground service. Then either a Broadcast Receiver, or use a `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` then `ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback`

Answer (score 0):

Using a service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

    return START_STICKY;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {

                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                    notifyMobileNetworkChange(context);
                }
                else {
                    notifyWifiNetworkChange(context);
                }

            }
....
}
```

Wake up app:

```
private void notifyMobileNetworkChange(Context context) {
    //Run anything you want here
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, WiFiName.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(dialogIntent);
}
```

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

You can find the complete project here:

https://github.com/stupidly-logical/WiFiName

You can modify the same for Mobile Data

Comment: as per OP question - "I'm looking for a solution to wake up my app whenever connectivity changes." - how does this answer do that?

Comment: @MarkKeen I added the answer for the OP to see that he can listen for connectivity changes. Still, I'll be happy to add a complete example.

Comment: I've added the complete code and edited the answer for same

Comment: it helps if you post the complete answer with the whole code structure. not snippets.

Comment: I've added link to the WHOLE PROJECT.